# iPhone Application works on simulator & when exported to device, but not via cydia

Tags: iphone

What I want to do:
Deploy an App to my phone using SCP without a dev license.

What Is Happening:
I can test on simulator and device and the Application works 100%.  When I scp the app to the Applications folder on my phone, the icon shows, and the app opens for about a couple of seconds then closes (you don't see anything except a black background).

I tried using ldid to sign it and the main binary is set to 0755 and chown'd to root:wheel.
I have tried various permission situations and the app pretty much does the same thing no matter what.

What is causing this to happen?  I know this is possible as EVERYONE who uploads apps to cydia follows this same process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The compiled binary on the device is an x86 binary, you need a different build for iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Check the syslog and see what it says when you tap the app icon. If it says "killed", download the ldid package from Cydia and cd to your application folder and sign it with ldid -S binaryname.

Also, are you compiling using the Open Toolchain or Apple's?